# Show that $(\mathcal C^0([a,b]),\|\cdot \|)$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\|f\|=\sup_{[a,b]}|f|$ where $f\in \mathcal C^0([a,b])$. I have to show that $(\mathcal C^0([a,b]),\|\cdot \|)$ is complete. I did as follow.

Let $x\in ]a,b[$. Let $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence. Since $\{f_n(x)\}\subset \mathbb R$ and that $$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \|f_n-f_m\|,$$
the sequence $(f_n(x))$ is a cauchy sequence and thus converge. Let denote $f(x)$ it's limit. We have to show that $f$ is continuous. Let $\varepsilon>0$. By continuity of $f_m$, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $u\in ]a,b[$, $|f_m(x)-f_m(u)|<\varepsilon/4$ whenever $|x-u|<\delta$. Let $n,m$ big enough to have $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon/4,\quad  |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon/4\quad \text{and}\quad |f_m(u)-f(u)|<\varepsilon/4.$$

Since 
$$|f(x)-f(u)|\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|+|f_m(x)-f_m(u)|+|f_m(u)-f(u)|,$$
we get $|f(x)-f(u)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-u|<\delta$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: You also need to show $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: it has a name : the [Uniform_limit_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof looks... okay, I guess. But it isn't complete, and the part that you have should be improved.

---

*Improvements:*

There is some confusion about which number you determine first.

For example, you say "By continuity of $f_m$, there is $\delta>0$ ...", but at the point where you say that, you haven't determined what $m$ is equal to.

---

**Part to add:**

You have now proven that the **pointwise** limit of $f_n$ is indeed a continuous function. You haven't shown, yet, that $f$ is also the limit of $f_n$ according to your norm. It shouldn't be hard, but you still need to prove that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N : (n>N)\implies\|f_n-f\| < \epsilon$$